# Tailwind-Elements to work with webpack encore defer attribute false

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

My projects is running with Symfony 5.4 and uses Webpack Encore Bundle.
I added Tailwind to it, no problem with that.

When I added Tailwind-Elements (TE) which adds some JS I had the following issue:

- TE works when config/packages/webpack_encore.yml defer script attribute is set to true
- But doesn't work when set to false

I can't set it to true because some other components (such as jQuery) don't work if defer set to true.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to make it work!

By default, only one js entrypoint is set (app.js).
The solution for me was to:

- Add another js entrypoint, (named it "defer_true_app.js")
- Import tailwind-elements in this new js file
- Add the entry in webpack.config.js:

  ```
    .addEntry('defer_true_app', './assets/defer_true_app.js')
  ```
- config/packages/webpack_encore.yml defer var is still set to false
- In my 'base.html.twig', I added in the {% block javascripts %} the defer_true entrypoint so it looks like this:

  ```
    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('defer_true_app', attributes={ defer: true }) }}
    {% endblock %}
  ```
- ```
     npm run build
  ```

And that's it!